# Remove comma from nth line of text file and add line break

Tags: php, text-files

I have a text file with line breaks that I have already imploded in to single line and added commas to the end of every line.

I need to remove every 36th comma from the line and add line break as well.

this is my code:

```
$lines = file("filename.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$comma_separated = implode(",", $lines);

$lines2 = preg_replace('/(?:[^,]*,){36}/', '$0\r\n', $comma_separated);
```

I have always had trouble with coding. My brains just don't go that way. I try my best, and I am 100 % sure I have searched and read the solution, but I have not understood it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather do something like this.
Instead of a regex that will eventually fail, add a string to every 36 line before you implode.
This string can easily be found with a simple str_replace() to remove and add the line break.

```
$lines = file("filename.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

For($i=0; $i<count($lines);){
    $lines[$i] .= "something";
    $i = $i+36;
}

$comma_separated = implode(",", $lines);
// String replace something to line break.
$result = str_replace("something,", "<br>", $comma_separated);
```

Edit sorry  the string replace of course needs to go after the implode.
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you!

This has been a pain in the rear for a while. I had to edit your code a bit; I put -1 insted of 0 at for($i=0.

Now it adds "something" at the end of the file, but that is no problem.

Comment: @Rautakannel ok! Good to hear it (almost) worked. Glad that you solved it!

Answer (score -1):

```
$lines = file("filename.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

For($i=0; $i<count($lines);){
    //your code
   if($i%36==0){
      trim($line,',');
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a never ending loop to me.